# Make messages i18n for specific directories or exclude directories

Tags: python, django, terminal, internationalization

My site structure looks like this:

```
project
--apps
----app1
----app2
--docs
--templates
----module1
----module2
----module3
```

how can I run

```
django-admin.py makemessages --locale=en
```

on all apps and template dirs but leave out module1 and module3?

Comment: why do you have python(?) modules in your templates folder?

Comment: they are templates of external django modules/apps...

Comment: This is far from an answer to your questions, but you can always run makemessages and just translate the phrases that interest you and leave the others alone. It's a drag, especially for big projects, but you can do a simple search on the paths of the modules you want to exclude and delete them before you start translating :)

Comment: unfortunately the project is too big for this kind of "manual" workflow

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have written a short script to iterate over the folders in my project directory and create translations if the folder contains a locale folder. The script which can be easily modified to exclude apps/directories if required

My project folder structure is

```
Project
--App1
----locale
--App2
----locale
--ProjectRoot - settings.py file is in ProjectRoot folder
----locale
etc
```

This script (`run_makemessages.py`) lives in the `Project` folder

```
import os
project_root = "/path/to/your/Project"
dirs = os.listdir(project_root)
for app in dirs:
    app_path = os.path.join(project_root, app)
    locale_path = os.path.join(app_path, "locale")
    if(os.path.exists(locale_path)): #modify this condition for exclusion of specific folders
        os.chdir(app_path)
        os.system("django-admin.py makemessages -a --no-wrap")
```

and is called with `python run_makemessages.py` - ie it's called directly and doesn't use django-admin or manage.py

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can, unless you write your own command, which will probably cost you more time then do them individually by accessing the required app's folder and running `../manage.py makemessages -l XX` from there